# Export emails from thunderbird to sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email

I need to load into sqlserver all of my locally stored email messages. Currently those are thunderbird-based but if i need some sort of export-to-outlook utility, fine, just say the word. I could probably adapt some asp.net (c#) code to access the local messages but doing the google against:

export emails from thunderbird to sql server
import to sqlserver from outlook

and a vast variation there of, is not getting me any closer to either a utility or someone's codeplex project.

it's probably trivial local file access stuff, so it's probably been done a few thousand times and has to have been presented as utility code a few hundred...but how do i find it?

thx

Comment: The problem that you are going to find is that virtually no one stores their Emails in SQL Server.  MS Exchange is the Email data-store of choice in the Windows world and that's what MS Outlook uses.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to setup a virtual machine or a server running linux (debian) or FreeBSD (my favorite). To install [postgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) and [DBmail](http://dbmail.org/) and to connect through IMAP to DBmail.

With dbmail it is possible to store all email into SQL.